# NSString operators (if string is bigger the other string)

Tags: objective-c, ios4, nsstring, operators

I have 3 strings.

```
NSString *hour1 = @"10:00";
NSString *hour2 = @"6:00";
NSString *hour3 = @"9:00";
```

How can I check which string has a bigger value? -> 10:00 > 9:00 > 6:00

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use [localizedStandardCompare:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

```
NSLog(@"%ld",[hour1 localizedStandardCompare:hour2]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the strings into an array,

```
NSString *hour1 = @"10:00";
NSString *hour2 = @"6:00";
NSString *hour3 = @"9:00";

NSArray *hours = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:hour1, hour2, hour3, nil];
```

Then sort the array,

```
NSArray *result = [hours sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2){
    return ([obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending);
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *hour1 = @"10:00";
NSString *hour2 = @"6:00";
NSString *hour3 = @"9:00";

// Convert the hours over to int's such as 1000, 600, and 900.
int hour1AsInt = [[hour1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@""] intValue];
int hour2AsInt = [[hour2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@""] intValue];
int hour3AsInt = [[hour3 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@""] intValue];

// Make the comparison's...  This could be more efficient but works well and is easy to follow:
if (hour1AsInt > hour2AsInt) {
    if (hour1AsInt > hour3AsInt) {
        NSLog(@"Hour 1 is biggest");
        return;
    }
}

if (hour2AsInt > hour1AsInt) {
    if (hour2AsInt > hour3AsInt) {
        NSLog(@"Hour 2 is biggest");
        return;
    }
}

if (hour3AsInt > hour1AsInt) {
    if (hour3AsInt > hour2AsInt) {
        NSLog(@"Hour 3 is biggest");
        return;
    }
}
```